# Laravel Internal server error

Tags: laravel, internal-server-error

My laravel 4 app is perfectly working in local environment but when migrated to the production environment the app throws Internal server error.Am i missing any changes to be done while migrating to the production ?

Comment: Have you made sure the mod rewrite extension is enabled on your production server?

Comment: There's a lot that could be throwing an internal server error... Incompatible php versions, un-writable `app/storage` folder, etc. Check your `app/config/production` folder (if you have one created), otherwise verify that all configuration settings are appropriate for your production environment.

Comment: @timLewis -You are right the issue was to due to incorrect file permisssions,i changed the file permission and now it is working perfectly :)

Comment: @SmitMehta Yeah, that's usually the culprit. If the `storage` folder isn't at least writable, the application will throw an error, but won't be able to display it (as it tries to save the error to a log in `app/storage/logs` folder before flashing it on screen). Glad you got it working though!

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems like that because I was declarating php arrays just using `['key'=>'value']` and my remote server didn't support that, so I had to switch all declarations to `array('key'=>'value')`